# In which layer should contain AutoMapper configurations?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, n-tier-architecture

In which layer should contain AutoMapper configurations?

AutoMapper is to map ViewModels to my Domain Entities.

I have three layers in my app: Domain, UI (MVC), Infrastructure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should live in the top most layer that it is translating to/from.

If you have mappers between domain and infra, then they should live in domain (assuming that uses infra).

If you have mappers between UI and domain, then they should live in UI (assuming that uses domain).

This means that the lower down layers do not know or need to know about the layers higher up.

Comment: I Have maps between UI (ViewModels) and Domain. If I put in Infrastructure, if I change UI tomorrow, is better?

Comment: @Acaz - I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: put automapper configurations in infrastructure is better because if i change the ui layer, the maps will stay?

Comment: @Acaz - Your infrastructure shouldn't know anything about your UI, as it should be lower level (UI can reference infrastructure, but references shouldn't be happening the other way around).

Comment: @Oded In an hexagonal architecture, the domain is in the center, so, the infrastructure layer is "on top" of the domain, at that moment, the mapper will live in the infrastructure layer, right ?

Comment: @Cromm - probably, unless the domain is about mapping ;)

Answer (score 2):

The place to map view models to domain models is typically the controller in an MVC architecture. Now you haven't said too much about your architecture, and "UI" and "Infra" aren't very specific.

Basically, though, you can call the AutoMapper configuration only in places where both the DomainModel and the ViewModel are known. Since the infrastructure should not depend on the ViewModels, you should map in the ViewModels (which depend on the domain model anyways), or the UI layer (which would be the controllers in MVC).

Comment: You are assuming MVC here, where the OP hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: It now is ;) Also, my answer is more generic in the end, taking MVC as a mere example. I felt it was helpful to be specific, and MVC is one of the most well-known patterns.